# ConTeXt : mutually exclusive modes

Tags: context

I was wondering if it was possible to define a group of modes, such as only one can be used. A MWE is :

```
\environment myEnvironment
\starttext
\startmode[modeA]
  This is mode A
\stopmode
\startmode[modeB]
  This is mode B
\stopmode
\stoptext
```

which displays "This is mode A" when run with 
`context --mode=modeA file.tex`
and "This is mode B" when run with 
`context --mode=modeB file.tex`

The bonus question is : is there a way to automatically (I mean without manually typing --result=newName) generate different output files (like file_modeA.pdf in the first case and file_modeB.pdf in the second).

Comment: For the first part see [Modes in the Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes#Checking_multiple_modes_in_parallel_.28case_statement_for_modes.29).  For the second part; no but that is a limitation of TeX.  The `\jobname` is fixed on startup but you can set the jobname from the command line and use a macro to parse for the corresponding mode and enable it.

Comment: If `modeA` and `modeB` are never set together, you can just use a single mode and test with `\startmode` and `\startnotmode`.

Comment: Or, if you want mutually exclusive modes, what is the desired output when I run `context --mode=modeA,modeB file.tex`?

Comment: It is not logical in my context to run it ; the example I was trying to implement was generating a lesson handout in two versions : one for students and one for the teacher.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to specifiy the mode alongside the result, just use the result name as the mode.   For example you can call the example below using

```
context --result=students test.tex
```

or

```
context --result=teachers test.tex
```

to enable the eponymous mode.  Because enabling the mode takes place at the Lua end you can of course construct much more sophisticated mode-checking constructs.

You can then check for the mode using all the available mode checking commands listed in the [Garden](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes).  Below I used `\doifmode` and `\doifnotmode` but the solution is not restricted to these.

```
\startluacode
context.enablemode{environment.arguments.result or ""}
\stopluacode

\starttext

\doifmode{students}{for student's eyes}
\doifnotmode{students}{for teacher's eyes}

\doifmode{teachers}{for teacher's eyes}
\doifnotmode{teachers}{for student's eyes}

\stoptext
```

Comment: This seems great. I'll try it as soon as I can.

Comment: @A.Licari Did it work?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try yet, I had an awful lot of tests to grade -_-